# What is this error Compiling a Fortran (f95) Code in OSX with gcc

Tags: macos, gcc, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile a Fortran (.f95) code in a Mac using gcc.
The code is an open source code. When I contacted the developers, they do not have the budget to provide a compiled application so they provide the files and let the user do the compiling.
Nevertheless I have failed at several attempts.
The code does come with a disclaimer of which files to compile and in which order. Nevertheless, just the first files encounters an error at a first pass.
This is the first section of the code that calls an error

```
     TYPE(GasParV), PARAMETER :: Methane = GasParV
 &       ("CH4   ", 2.514d1,                                     ! Name, AtomDV
```

The error is

```
HRS_RealGasEOS.f95:85:54:

          TYPE(GasParV), PARAMETER :: Methane = GasParV
                                                  1
Error: Function 'gasparv' requires an argument list at (1)
```

Comment: It looks like fixed-form source.  You should look how to compile such things.

Comment: Welcome. Please show us how exactly you are compiling the files when you get this error and a bigger pece of the code. Show us the exact command you type. See [ask] and [mcve]. Alse take the welcome [tour].

Comment: Hi, I am using the code gfortran -c file.f95. I found 2 lines in the instruction manual that mentioned 2 things for compiling: (1) Fixed format source code (72 columns) and (2) Automatically promote REAL type variables to REAL (KIND = 8)(double precision). I more or less know hot to do nr 1, but no clue about nr 2. Thanks

Comment: This is the command I have been using: gfortran -c File.f95 -ffixed-form -freal-4-real-8

Comment: You're sure you're compiling that file with `-ffixed-form`?  It seems the compiler is treating it as free form.  [Perhaps try renaming the file to use `.f` instead of `.f95` as suffix.]  Also, the `&` is in the sixth column, and it's just pasting here which swallowed four spaces  (you can add those back in to indent correctly in the question)?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It seems that FORTRAN is quite simple but it has a lot of rules to make it work. I feels somehow spoiled by how good Python or Matlab lay the groundwork for the user.